# I can't get the pivot point of an Image view in Android

Tags: android

...and it's making me question my will to live.

invoking getPivotX and getPivotY() just gives me 350.0 regardless of where the Image view actually is on screen. I am invoking this method inside of my override of onTouchEvent.

I am trying to create a knob that my user can use to set a timer. I need to know where the center of my imageview is so that I can calculate the angle the knob needs to point to. My code is

```
int knobCenterX = (int) knob.getPivotX();
int knobCenterY = (int) knob.getPivotY();
```

this gives me (350, 350) for the coordinates every time, and whats absurd is that can't be the pivot because Im able to rotate the image view for the knob around its true center when I use the following code

```
knob.setRotation((float) angle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried something like this before?

```
int[] location = new int[2];
textView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"X axis is "+location[0] +"and Y axis is "+location[1],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: So this is one of the first things I tried. The issue is that when a view rotates I can no longer find the center of the view by adding one half of the width and height to the x and Y coordinates. I really, really just need to find the pivot point of my image view but getPivotX and getPivotY always return 350 for me, regardless of where the view is on the screen which can't be the true pivot point because thats not the location of the center of the view.

Comment: Did you set the pivotpoint in the mid of the view in your xml file with android:pivotX=50%"

Comment: So hey it turns out that the pivot point is not relative to the size of the screen but is in fact relative to the size of the view. The view is 700x700 hence the center would be (350,350), which would be why regardless of where the view was on screen I would still get (350,350).